# Error en Mis proyectos en Apps Script

Tags: script, google-apps-script

Ayer estuve trabajando con *Google Apps Script* y todo funcionaba perfectamente haciendo lo que le solicitaba en los comandos,  pero hoy ya no me permite ingresar a  **Mis Proyectos** o **Todos los Proyectos**.

Me arroja un error diciendo:

> Se ha producido un error
>   **Vuelva a cargar la página e inténtalo de nuevo**
>   Cerrar - Volver a cargar

[image: Error]

[image: evidencia de que estaba funcionando]

Si ingreso a **Mis ejecuciones**, se muestra que venía trabajando bien la aplicación. ¿Cómo se soluciona esto?  He probado con otro usuario y todo carga correctamente, necesito poder ver mis proyectos en esta cuenta.

Comment: ¿Qué ha pasado? ¿Te sirvió mi respuesta? ¿Continua tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente el error tiene que ver con https://script.google.com.

- Lo primero a intentar es usar tu navegador en modo incógnito con
  todas las extensiones inhabilitadas
- Si el problem persiste, intenta
  con otro navegador.
- Si el problema continua repórtalo a Google usando Google Feedback

  [image]

La solución provisional mas sencilla es acceder a tus proyectos de Google Apps Script desde Google Drive. Otra solución provisional es usar [CLASP](https://github.com/google/clasp), la cual es es una aplicación de línea de comandos.

NOTA:

Hay una pregunta similar en Web Applications a la que también respondí [Odd Google Apps Script behavior](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114280/88163). Hasta Septiembre de 2019, no había confirmación de AP de que se hubiera resuelto su caso.